# Show "cannot find declaration to go" when i click on dimen in XML file in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, declaration

When I was clicked on below tag on android studio, it lead me to dimen

```
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
```

but now when i click on it, it show me this Error

```
Cannot find declaration to go to
```

I search on stackoverflow but none of them doesn't work for me.
Its notable that I had this problem before and after a while it solve by itself.

Could you help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: post your "@dimen/button_height" file here.Or its spell mistake ...dimens

Comment: no its not spelling mistake, i exactly copy the code here. I have similar problem with color and string such as:  android:textColor="@color/login_text_color"

Answer (score 0):

here is what fixed it for me:

1. close the project.
2. go to the project folder and delete the .idea folder
3. restart android studio and open the project 
   wait for the indexing to finish.

Comment: Actually, I did it. but it didn't work for me. but about several hours ago, i solved my problem. i post it.

Answer (score 0):

I could find solution for my problem

This works for me:

1- close android studio

2- go to C:\Users(your user)

3- remove .AndroidStudio3.4 folder.

Then run android studio.

If this doesn't work, first uninstall android studio then repeat above steps